# ASP.NET WebApi SelfHost service fails on HTTP URL registration

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

I am trying to host an ASP.NET WebApi endpoint on an Azure worker role using the new Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost NuGet package.  My worker's Run() code looks roughly like this:

```
// Endpoint is defined as in ServiceDefinition.csdef as 
//   HTTP, external port 8080, internal port 8080 (or 8081 - error both ways)
RoleInstanceEndpoint externalEndPoint =
    RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Endpoint"]; 
string baseAddress= String.Format("http://{0}", externalEndPoint.IPEndpoint);
var maxsize = 1024 * 1024;  
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress) 
{ 
    MaxBufferSize = maxsize, MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxsize 
};
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

// Create and open the server
var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
server.OpenAsync().Wait();

// keep the worker thread alive
while (true)
    Thread.Sleep(Timeout);
```

This works fine in the dev fabric, but when deploying to Azure, I get an AggregateException from the server.OpenAsync() call, containing the following exception stack:

```
[0] One or more errors occurred.
[1] HTTP could not register URL http://+:8081/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).
[2] Access is denied
```

I'm just running a vanilla worker role and this seems to be the "hello world" of self-host...

The endpoint part of my ServiceDefinition.csdef looks like this:

```
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint" protocol="http" port="8080" localPort="8081" />
</Endpoints>
```

The baseAddress that I get from the RoleEnvironment InstanceEndpoint looks legit - http://10.115.[X].[Y]:8081

I see the failure whether I use the same port/localPort (8080) or when I do a mapping, like the above.

It's clear that it's possible to host a conventional WCF service in a worker role in this way - is there any reason why ASP.NET WebApi SelfHost wouldn't work in this configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the RoleEntryPoint runs under a very minimal permission user account for security.  As the error indicates, it is unable to reserve that port due to those permissions.  You have two options here:

1. Run the Worker process as SYSTEM by adding the Runtime element to your role definition (i.e `<Runtime executionContext="elevated"/>`).
2. Create a startup script that runs elevated and reserves that port for you.

For playing around (and troubleshooting if it is a permission issue), doing #1 is a quick way to test it.

Edit:  I seem to recall a permission issue with WCF and Windows Azure when doing wildcard reservations.  It used to work fine when using the full hostname e.g.

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(
 typeof(IEchoService), new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None) { HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact }, "echo");
```

Comment: Hey Ryan - many thanks!  I figured it was some permissioning issue.  #1 is a pretty big hammer... I will do it if I need to, but I was hoping to do something a bit more surgical... like run netsh in an elevated startup script - something like "netsh.exe http add urlacl url="http://+:8080" but I need to grant permission to a user, and I don't really know the name/SID of the account that Azure will run the worker role under... is there a way to find that out, or to run netsh.exe in a way that allows access on that port to all users?

Comment: Hmm... now that I look closer, I think it is because you are doing a wildcard reservation.  If you just updated the code to target the exact IP address and port, I think you can get around the permission problem.  IIRC, it is only wildcard reservations that need to be elevated to ACL.  See updated answer.

Comment: When I trace the value of "baseAddress" in the above code, it comes out like this: http://10.115.210.79:8080.  So I'm actually using an exact match... furthermore, the odd thing is that even if I add a line to the startup script that does "netsh.exe http add urlacl url="http://+:8080" user=everyone", and verify that it executes correctly (and that the permissions are right when I do a "netsh http urlacl show"), I *STILL* get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

After half a dev-day experimenting with invoking netsh.exe from an elevated startup script to no avail, I gave up and ended up using the big hammer and taking Ryan's initial suggestion of running the entire worker role elevated:

```
<WorkerRole name="WorkerRole" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
  <Runtime executionContext="elevated">
  </Runtime>
</WorkerRole>
```

That solved all issues.

For reference, here is how I tried to allow HTTP registration for non-elevated user accounts (which never really worked):

In ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<Startup>
  <Task executionContext="elevated" commandLine="startup\Install.cmd">
    <Environment>
      <Variable name="ENDPOINTPORT ">
        <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/Endpoints/Endpoint[@name='Endpoint']/@port" />
      </Variable>
    </Environment>
  </Task>
</Startup>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint" protocol="http" port="8080" localPort="8080" />
</Endpoints>
```

And in the startup script (startup\Install.cmd in my case):

```
netsh.exe http add urlacl url=http://+:%ENDPOINTPORT%/api user=everyone listen=yes delegate=yes
```

This is basically the solution that was recommended by the good folks working on AspNetWebApi (just a shorter way of doing what they recommend [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/WCF-Azure-Worker-Role-on-b394df49)), but unfortunately it didn't work for me - while the netsh command executed successfully and I was able to verify that the urlacl on the URL I am self-hosting on (http://+:8080/api/) is allowed by \Everyone, I was still getting the same permission error.  If anyone figures out how to make this work when running the worker-role non-elevated, please post!

Comment: I ran the script one time in cmd, but I had to run as administrator: who do you run your startup script as? Another ref [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api)

Comment: By default Azure does not run its roles in elevated accounts, but in fairly restricted user accounts that don't have predictable names (they are GUIDs that get created when the fabric controller preps the VM).  Azure does allow running startup scripts in an elevated (Admin) account - which is what the <Startup><Task executionContext="elevated"...></> in my code does.  But for some reason the netsh.exe still didn't succeed in allowing the command.  I ended up having to run that entire role elevated (which solved the issues).

Comment: Oops, sorry, I skipped over the 'Azure' detail!

Answer (score -1):

Add reference 'System.ServiceModel' to your project and with the 'config.HostNameComparisonMode = System.ServiceModel.HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;' you don't get the administrator privileges exception (access denied).

Comment: A little comment please ?